# Java generics nested classes

Tags: java, generics, nested

I am getting the following *error: cannot find symbol* error when trying to implement a nested generics structure in JDK7 to represent a 1 to many relationship.

Activities has 1 to many Activity and Session.
Activity has 1 to many Lap and Training.
Lap has 1 to many Track.
Track has to 1 to many TrackPoint.

```
public class Activities<Activity, Session> {
   private ArrayList<Activity> activities; //with getter and setter
```

.....
    }

```
public class Activity<Lap,Training> {
   private ArrayList<Lap> laps;// with getter and setter
   private ArrayList<Training> trainings;
}
```

and so on.

When i try to get activities.getActivities(), I get the compilation error.

```
ArrayList<Activity> activities = (ArrayList<Activity>)activities.getActivities();
```

Do I need to define it like `ArrayList<Activity<Lap<Track<TrackPoint>>>>,Training> ?`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] which we can feed to the java compiler to immediately see the issue?

Comment: `ArrayList<Activity> activities = (ArrayList<Activity>)activities.getActivities();` doesn't make sense. You can't call `getActivities()` on `activities` while you define the variable `activities`.

Comment: @marstran That was what i found out too- I cannot use the same variable name activities - Duh!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo: you are declaring the variable `activities` that you're already using:

```
ArrayList<Activity> activities = (ArrayList<Activity>)activities.getActivities();
```

Try this instead:

```
ArrayList<Activity> foo = (ArrayList<Activity>)activities.getActivities();
```

You don't event need the cast anymore:

```
ArrayList<Activity> foo = activities.getActivities();
```